# asp.NET Response on Postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, response, postback

Basically I have a form that I validate. On successful validation I clear the form, show a response label saying everything was successful and give a PDF download as response which has the form the user just filled out as PDF.

My problem is that once the PDF downloads the page doesn't postback so the form doesn't clear and the label isn't shown. I need to find a way to start the download AFTER the postback, so that the form has cleared and the label is shown.

Comment: Could you just make the PDF available on click of a link(button), rather than forcing the download directly after save?

Comment: You can use `SetTimeout` function of JQuery !

Comment: What is the code of download? It sounds like postback is there (otherwise, how does pdf download start?) but you have something like Response.End after that, which can stop processing the form refresh.

Comment: `Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
                page.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
                page.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

                page.Response.BinaryWrite(output.ToArray());
                page.Response.End();` That is the code I'm using for the download. And yeah, I have another place where the download is available for the User, however, I also want to give them the download straight away when they submit as it seems more intuitive.